# How to keep the screen on server in same state (with the splits intact) as it was left?

Tags: linux

I have been using the "screen" command to detach a running program from my college's server. But every time when I reopen the screen I have to recreate the horizontal and vertical splits in the screen. Is there a way that they could remain in place even after I have closed the server connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tmux` with `tmux-resurrect` and `tmux-continuum` plugins and you can have some really powerful environment.

Not only your sessions persists the `tmux` server exit but with right settings they can persist even system reboots and can go to the extent of having `ssh` sessions saved as well. Here is snippet of my settings for these plugins. So in my case I am asking `tmux-continuum` to save my sessions every 5 min and I want `ssh` program to persist `tmux` exit and system reboots. I also have setting to keep my `vim` and `neovim` sessions restored as such.

```
# TPM settings

set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect'
set -g @resurrect-capture-pane-contents 'on'
set -g @resurrect-processes 'ssh'
# for vim
set -g @resurrect-strategy-vim 'session'
# for neovim
set -g @resurrect-strategy-nvim 'session'

set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum'
set -g @continuum-restore 'on'
set -g @continuum-save-interval '5'
```

You can read more about `tmux-resurrect` [here](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) and `tmux-continuum` [here](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum)

On a side note you can have default layouts that you want to have created when you launch `tmux` with different combinations of windows and panes which and then run different program in each pane.

Here is a very simple shell script that I use for my certain project.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session  -s "dev" -n "home" \; \
        split-window -v -p 40 \; \
        split-window -h -p 60 \; \
        new-window -n 'py37' \; \
        send-keys 'cdp3' C-m  'c' C-m \; \
        split-window -v -p 30 \; \
        send-keys 'cdp3' C-m 'c' C-m \; \
        split-window -h -p 75 \; \
        send-keys 'cdp3' C-m 'c' C-m \; \
        select-pane -t 1 \; \
        new-window -n 'py2' \; \
        send-keys 'cdp2' C-m 'c' C-m \; \
        split-window -v -p 30 \; \
        send-keys 'cdp2' C-m 'c' C-m \; \
        split-window -h -p 75 \; \
        send-keys 'cdp2' C-m 'c' C-m \; \
        select-pane -t 1 \; \
        select-window -t 1 \; \
        select-pane -t 1 \
```

`split-window` will split the current window into panes either horizontally or vertically with height width specified in percentage

`new-window` will create the new window in the session.

`select-pane` will select the pane with the specified pane-id

Whatever you see after `send-keys` is the actual command or program you want to run in that pane.

With this script ready all i have to do is execute it and i will have a new `tmux` session with pre-defined layout. You can extend this as much as you want to your needs.

Hope this helps you in moving from legacy `screen` to a modern and much more flexible solution `tmux`.

Comment: I am just who and why this answer was down voted, `tmux` is a much better alternative to `screen` and if someone down voted just because I didn't answer in context of screen it is because of the fact that screen lot of features that `tmux` brings and sooner or later `tmux` is worth a shot.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, I actually liked the answer.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, pls accept the answer if it solves ur issue or help u in any way

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I suspect it's because you're answering off-topic questions. If the question isn't about programming flag it as off-topic rather than answering it

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for the pro tip, i guess this might be the issue my answers are being downvoted.